# Pandas group hourly data into daily sums with date index

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I am working on a code that takes hourly data for a month and groups it into 24 hour sums.  My problem is that I would like the index to read the date/year and I am just getting an index of 1-30.

**The code I am using is**

```
df = df.iloc[:,16:27].groupby([lambda x: x.day]).sum()
```

**example of output I am getting**

```
DateTime     data
1            1772.031568
2            19884.42243
3            28696.72159
4            24906.20355
5            9059.120325
```

**example of output I would like**

```
DateTime     data
1/1/2017     1772.031568
1/2/2017     19884.42243
1/3/2017     28696.72159
1/4/2017     24906.20355
1/5/2017     9059.120325
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your index is a `datetime`, you can build a combined `groupby` clause:

```
df = df.iloc[:,16:27].groupby([lambda x: "{}/{}/{}".format(x.day, x.month, x.year)]).sum()
```

or even better:

```
df = df.iloc[:,16:27].groupby([lambda x: x.strftime("%d%m%Y")]).sum()
```

Comment: Just for the record, I recommend you to set the `groupby` token as `%Y%m%d`, since that way it is easier to get the elements ordered by date (if you ever need that).

Answer (score 9):

This is an old question, but I don't think the accepted solution is the best in this particular case. What you want to accomplish is to down sample time series data, and Pandas has built-in functionality for this called [resample()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html#pandas.DataFrame.resample). For your example you will do:

```
df = df.iloc[:,16:27].resample('D').sum()
```

or if the datetime column is not the index

```
df = df.iloc[:,16:27].resample('D', on='datetime_column_name').sum()
```

There are (at least) 2 benefits from doing it this way as opposed to accepted answer:

1. Resample can up sample and down sample, groupby() can only down sample
2. No lambdas, list comprehensions or date formatting functions required.

For more information and examples, see documentation here: [resample()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html#pandas.DataFrame.resample)

Comment: This is a more elegant answer, and more up-to date

Answer (score 2):

if your index was not datetime object.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'data': [1772.031568, 19884.42243,28696.72159, 24906.20355,9059.120325]},index=[1,2,3,4,5])
print df.head()
rng = pd.date_range('1/1/2017',periods =len(df.index), freq='D')
df.set_index(rng,inplace=True)
print df.head()
```

will result in

```
           data
1   1772.031568
2  19884.422430
3  28696.721590
4  24906.203550
5   9059.120325
                    data
2017-01-01   1772.031568
2017-01-02  19884.422430
2017-01-03  28696.721590
2017-01-04  24906.203550
2017-01-05   9059.120325
```

Answer (score 1):

First you need to create an index on your datetime column to expose functions that break the datetime into smaller pieces efficiently (*like the year and month of the datetime*).

Next, you need to group by the year, month and day of the index if you want to apply an aggregate method (like `sum()`) to each day of the year, and retain separate aggregations for each day.

The `reset_index()` and `rename()` functions allow us to rename our **group_by** categories to their original names. This "flattens" out our data, making the category an actual column on the resulting dataframe.

```
import pandas as pd

date_index = pd.DatetimeIndex(df.created_at)
# 'df.created_at' is the datetime column in your dataframe
counted = df.group_by([date_index.year, date_index.month, date_index.day])\
            .agg({'column_to_sum': 'sum'})\
            .reset_index()\
            .rename(columns={'level_1': 'year',
                             'level_2': 'month',
                             'level_3': 'day'})

# Resulting dataframe has columns "column_to_sum", "year", "month", "day" available
```

Answer (score 0):

You can exploit panda's `DatetimeIndex`:

```
working_df=df.iloc[:, 16:27]
result = working_df.groupby(pd.DatetimeIndex(working_df.DateTime)).date).sum()
```

This if you DateTime column is actually DateTime (and be careful of the timezone).

In this way you will have valid datetime in the index, so that you can easily do other manipulations.